# how to inherit all things in another class, using base

Tags: c#

noob question in c#:

I have:

```
public class c
{
    public int XYZ;
}

public class b : c {
    ...
}

public class a : b {
    ...
    base.XYZ = 0; //<----
    ...
}
```

I want to reference `XYZ` declared in `c`.

please dont tell me that this is bad to access property/method of base's base.
I have hundreds of things in `c` and cant redeclare them one-by-one in `b`.

Can there be made something ALL-IN-ONE declaration in `b`, which commands the c#, to call it's base (`c`) property/method, when `b` doesnt include that property/method?

Comment: Why would you think it does not work? Do you get errors?

Comment: **It is not clear what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer.** For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [ask] a good question.

Comment: Try "this.XYZ" in class a instead

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think this does not work? This is compileable and working sample - does what you are asking for.

```
void Main()
{
    var a = new A();
    a.CProperty = 42;
}


public class C {
    public int CProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B : C
{
    // nothing
}

public class A : B{
    // nothing
}
```

Here is a [DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7DckJC)